# Is this how you correctly calculate a Vector3 Transform and TransformCoordinate?

Tags: c++, math, directx, game-physics

I have been looking into how the D3DXVec3Transform and D3DXVec3TransformCoord functions are operating was wondering if this is the correct way the math should be, if not, could someone please explain why. I understand that there are already DirectX functions to do this, however, I have been attempting to learn more about the math behind the scenes and from research I have come to this.

```
D3DXVECTOR3 Vec3Transform(D3DXVECTOR3 &vCoordinate, D3DXMATRIX &mTransform)
{
    D3DXVECTOR3 vWorking;

    vWorking.x = (vCoordinate.x * mTransform._11) + (vCoordinate.y * mTransform._21) + (vCoordinate.z * mTransform._31) + mTransform._41;
    vWorking.y = (vCoordinate.x * mTransform._12) + (vCoordinate.y * mTransform._22) + (vCoordinate.z * mTransform._32) + mTransform._42;
    vWorking.z = (vCoordinate.x * mTransform._13) + (vCoordinate.y * mTransform._23) + (vCoordinate.z * mTransform._33) + mTransform._43;

    return D3DXVECTOR3(vWorking.x, vWorking.y, vWorking.z);
}

D3DXVECTOR3 Vec3TransformCoordinate(D3DXVECTOR3 &vCoordinate, D3DXMATRIX &mTransform)
{
    D3DXVECTOR4 vWorking;

    vWorking.x = (vCoordinate.x * mTransform._11) + (vCoordinate.y * mTransform._21) + (vCoordinate.z * mTransform._31) + mTransform._41;
    vWorking.y = (vCoordinate.x * mTransform._12) + (vCoordinate.y * mTransform._22) + (vCoordinate.z * mTransform._32) + mTransform._42;
    vWorking.z = (vCoordinate.x * mTransform._13) + (vCoordinate.y * mTransform._23) + (vCoordinate.z * mTransform._33) + mTransform._43;
    vWorking.w = 1 / ((vCoordinate.x * mTransform._14) + (vCoordinate.y * mTransform._24) + (vCoordinate.z * mTransform._34) + mTransform._44);

    return D3DXVECTOR3(vWorking.x * vWorking.w, vWorking.y * vWorking.w, vWorking.z * vWorking.w);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at similar functions in the D3DX Library it seems you have implemented their function faithfully.

It may also help to have a function which transforms (x,y,z,0) by a 4x4 matrix as this is useful when translating directions, such as an object's velocity or a surface's normal. The vector will be transformed without translations being applied, which would have ruined the direction.

Comment: D3DXMATRIX is a 4x4 matrix, does that change your opinion about the answer?

Comment: Because the matrix is 4x4 the function in your question above treats a 3 dimensional vector (x,y,z) as a 4 dimensional vector, specifically (x,y,z,1), which is appropriate for transforming positions. But for directions (such as velocities, normals etc.) a translation would be nonsensical, so you may wish to also have a function that treats the 3 dimensional vector (x,y,z) as (x,y,z,0), which would not have translation applied.

Comment: I will be honest, you answered a comment to a nearly nine year old comment. I have no idea what I was doing nine years ago. So much as change in my life. But it looks like we are both programming. Thank you for the help